# How to mock Hawk library using Mockito?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, mockito, integration-testing

I'm trying to do some unit testing with `Mockito`. Because I'm using `Hawk` library as `SharedPreference` to apply some constraints when I do my API calls, every time I run a test that implies an API call I get a NullPointerException because `Hawk` is not initialized.

By default the library is initialized on the `Application` class level:

```
Hawk.init(context).build();
```

Although I'm using a mocked `context` to initialize `Hawk` in my test class, as in the following snippet:

```
@Mock
private lateinit var context: Context

@Before
fun initMocks() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    Hawk.init(context).build()
}
```

I keep getting this error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.facebook.android.crypto.keychain.SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain.<init>(SharedPrefsBackedKeyChain.java:65)
at com.orhanobut.hawk.ConcealEncryption.<init>(ConcealEncryption.java:17)
at com.orhanobut.hawk.HawkBuilder.getEncryption(HawkBuilder.java:93)
at com.orhanobut.hawk.DefaultHawkFacade.<init>(DefaultHawkFacade.java:12)
at com.orhanobut.hawk.Hawk.build(Hawk.java:27)
at com.orhanobut.hawk.HawkBuilder.build(HawkBuilder.java:109)
at com.terma.ds.rm.clientandroid.activity.radar_list.RadarListModelTest.initMocks(RadarListModelTest.kt:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:68)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:74)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:161)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Is there a way to mock the `Hawk` library using `Mockito`?

Answer (score 0):

> How to mock Hawk library using Mockito?

Wrap it trough a nice interface or use a version of mockito that allows to mock static like `PowerMockito`

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: what kind of example ? Wrapping ?

Answer (score 0):

As @Blackbelt informed.
You don't need to test library. So instead of mocking library.
Create an interface class. Wrap all access to library through method implementation inside interface. And while testing use below code:

```
doNothing().when(maukInterface.blablaMethod());
```